# Entity framework core не подгружаются связи многие ко многим

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Есть 2 модели:

```
public class Class
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ExamInfo> ExamInfos { get; set; }

    public Class()
    {
        ExamInfos = new List<ExamInfo>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class ExamInfo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime dateExam { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //какие классы будут сдавать экзамен
    public ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    public ExamInfo()
    {
        Classes=new List<Class>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Для них соответственно создалась автоматически таблица

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExamInfoClasses] (
    [ExamInfo_id] INT NOT NULL,
    [Class_id]    INT NOT NULL
);
```

Но когда я пытаюсь получить связанные данные, то всегда список пуст, причём с обеих сторон. Что не так?

```
using (var db = new EntityContext())
{
    if (dataGridViewStudents.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
        return;
    //подгружаем данные из БД
    var classes=db.Classes.ToList();

    //ВОТ ТУТ В ОТЛАДЧИКЕ СМОТРЮ И ВСЕГДА Classes пусто
    db.ExamInfos.ToList();

    //получаем первую попавшуюся строку
    int index = dataGridViewStudents.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    int id = 0;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(dataGridViewStudents[0, index].Value.ToString(), out id))
        return;
    var student = db.Students.Find(id);
    if (student.currentClass == null)
        return;

    //ВОТ ТУТ ВСЕГДА ПУСТО
    var examInfosList=student.currentClass.ExamInfos.ToList();

    List<ExamResult> examResults= new List<ExamResult>();
    foreach(ExamInfo examInfo in examInfosList)
    {
        var examResult= db.ExamResults.Where(exR=>exR.exam==examInfo && exR.student==student).FirstOrDefault();
        if (examResult == null)
            examResult = new ExamResult() {exam=examInfo,student=student };
        examResults.Add(examResult);
    }
    dataGridViewExam.DataSource = examResults;
}
```

Заполнял так:

```
//создаём два объекта Class
Class class1 = new Class { Name = "5Б" };
Class class2 = new Class { Name = "6А" };

ExamInfo examInfo1 = new ExamInfo {dateExam=new DateTime(2022,1,15),Classes=new List<Class> {class1,class2}, Name = "Физика" };
ExamInfo examInfo2 = new ExamInfo {dateExam = new DateTime(2022, 1, 15), Classes = new List<Class> {class1},Name="Математика" };
```

Comment: Не так здесь то, что вы не указали необходимые метки. Поэтому вопрос остался незамеченным. И вот: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11968/184217 - показывайте свою заинтересованность в получении ответа

Answer (score 1):

1. Приведены только модели, а отношений между моделями нет.
2. Связанные данные не загружаются автоматически, об этом надо позаботиться:

```
    var classes=db.Classes
                  .Include(x=>x.ExamInfos)
                  .ToList();
```